# What is the outer kink on the airbus 340-600?

Tags: wing, airbus, airbus-a340

I was checking some information about the a340-600 and got this statement: "thickness/ chord ratios 15.25 per cent at root, 11.27 per cent at inner kink, 9.86 per cent at outer kink and 10.60 per cent at tip" 
I know where the inner kink is but what is the outer kink and where is it located?

Comment: I edited a few things to make your question a little more readable.  If I deleted anything important, feel free or roll back the changes.  Welcome to Aviation.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outer kink on A340-600 wing is located just outboard of the outboard engine, note trailing edge kink in [planform drawing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A340#/media/File%3AA340FAMILY2v1.0.png).

Comment: it is not that visible at first glance

Comment: @IbrahimJaafar Indeed not, but a straightedge helps ;)